# Randomize related posts in Docpad

Tags: docpad

I've installed the [Related](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-related/) plugin for docpad and what I want to do is I want it to display five random related posts in the sidebar of every blogpost. At the moment I have it set up this way in my `post.html.jade`:

```
div
  h4 Related posts:
  each doc in getRelatedDocuments().slice(0,5)
    a(href=doc.url)= doc.title
    br
```

So, it displays 5 posts, but they aren't random. How do I shuffle the output of `getRelatedDocuments()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Steve Mc for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up creating this function in `docpad.coffee`:

```
shufflePosts: (items) ->
  i = items.length
  return items if i == 0
  while --i
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    tmp = items[i]
    items[i] = items[j]
    items[j] = tmp
  return items
```

It is basically an implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm. And in my post layout I call it using:

```
each doc in shufflePosts(getRelatedDocuments()).slice(0,5)
  a(href=doc.url)= doc.title
  br
```

So now everything's great, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sold on whether this is the best way to do this. I can see problems if the collection is large or the website high volume. It would be better if this could be done using the query engine syntax (https://learn.bevry.me/queryengine/guide) - but even then you might want to cache the results.

Comment: @SteveMc sure, but how can I use query engine to get posts with similar tags? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Sorry - it's not the related posts part I was thinking of its more extracting a whole collection to shuffle/randomise and then slicing it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a variation on the question [Getting random value from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array)?

I created a function in the docpad.coffee file to implement this solution:

```
getRandomPosts: (howMany) ->
    items = @getCollection('posts').toJSON()
    output = []
    i = 0
    while i < howMany
        doc = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)]
        output.push(doc)
        i++

    return output
```

You may need an extra step in the while loop to check if the doc value is already in the output array as Math.floor etc could possibly return a value already used.